# What is the point of this constant in Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

In Kohana's core class, there is a constant [`FILE_SECURITY`](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Kohana#constant%3aFILE_SECURITY).

```
string(60) "<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');"
```

Now obviously if you place this at the start of your files, and if it is accessed outside of the Kohana environment, it will `die()`.

But what is the purpose of this constant? We can't `eval()` it because it has a leading `<?php`.

Does Kohana create PHP files somewhere and uses it to prepend it to the start of the file?

Comment: +1 from someone who doesn't use Kohana but is interested in it's developemnt/design

Comment: `eval` won't matter, the constant `SYSPATH` will still be found undefined and result into `die`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Kohana_Log_File::write` function](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Kohana_Log_File#write) uses the constant:

```
// Set the name of the log file
$filename = $directory.date('d').EXT;

if ( ! file_exists($filename))
{
    // Create the log file
    file_put_contents($filename, Kohana::FILE_SECURITY.' ?>'.PHP_EOL);

    // Allow anyone to write to log files
    chmod($filename, 0666);
}
```

Looks like it's inserted into a log to stop it from being read from a public URL.

Comment: Googled the constant name, went to the API docs and read the `write` function.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that. Don't know why I didn't think of that actually - or searched on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this constant while autogenerating your custom files, like configs (possible in installation apps?).